# Upload and view an input file using VueJS

Tags: javascript, typescript, haml, vue.js

I am using TypeScript and Haml. I want to be able to upload and view a file using vue.js. I am able to upload an image but it is supposed to display it right away as demoed here: https://codepen.io/Atinux/pen/qOvawK/

Instead, I get this error:

http://localhost:8080/image Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

If it's trying to get the image from the root directory, is my issue that I'm not saving it there? How would I solve this?

page_image.ts:

```
require("./page_image.scss");
import Vue = require("vue");
import {Injections} from "../../init";

export const PageImage = {
template: require("./page_image.haml"),
data: function () {
    return {
        image: ''
    }
},

created() {
    Injections.HeaderTextManager.setHeader("Videos");
    Injections.HeaderTextManager.clearDescription();
},

methods: {
    onFileChange(e:any) {
        var files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;
        if (!files.length)
            return;
        this.createImage(files[0]);
    },
    createImage(file:any) {
        var image = new Image();
        var reader = new FileReader();
        var vm = this;

        reader.onload = (e:any) => {
            vm.image = e.target.result;
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    },
    removeImage: function (e:any) {
        this.image = '';
    }
}
};
```

page_image.haml:

```
.page-image
  .row
  .col-xs-12
    .box
      .box-header
        %div(v-if="!image")
          %h3.box-title Upload an image
          %input(type="file" v-on:change="onFileChange")
        %div(v-else)
          %img(src="image" name="image")
          %img {{image}}
          %button(v-on:click="removeImage") Remove image
```

Comment: Your code is only reading the image in the browser itself. You have to then use an XHR of some sort to send it to the server before you will be able to then turn around and load it from the server.

Comment: You know you could use `URL.createObjectURL(file)` instead of using the filereader...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know `haml`, and I do not use typescript with `vue.js`. So I cannot give you a direct answer.

Here is a working jsFiddle example that implements `FileReader` with `vue.js` to provide an instant preview:
https://jsfiddle.net/mani04/5zyozvx8/

You may use the above for reference to debug your code.

Here is how it works:  To make FileReader work properly, we need access to the DOM element for `input`. This can be accomplished as shown below:

```html
<input type="file" @change="previewImage" accept="image/*">
```

The `previewImage` method gets the `event` parameter, which has `event.target` - the DOM element for `input` that we need. Now your `previewImage` method can read the image file normally as follows:

```js
previewImage: function(event) {
    // Reference to the DOM input element
    var input = event.target;
    // Ensure that you have a file before attempting to read it
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        // create a new FileReader to read this image and convert to base64 format
        var reader = new FileReader();
        // and so on...
```

You may use this jsFiddle for reference, and keep this question open, so that others with knowledge of `haml` and `typescript` may provide a more direct answer.

Comment: Please ignore my answer above... It is the same as codePen example you gave, I noticed it only now.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is caused because of this line in your page_image.haml

```
%img(src="image" name="image")
```

If it translates or compiles to `<image src="image" name="image">`, then your browser will look for image in `localhost:8080/image` instead of attempting to show from `data.image` inside Vue component.

As explained in my other answer, I dont know `haml`, so you have to figure out a way to fix it yourself.

**Edit:**

Looking at the other `haml` code in your question, does this work?

```
%img(v-bind:src="image" name="image")
```